# Multiple instances of the same application to test using Spectron

Tags: electron, spectron

I am trying to have two separate instances of the same application running in a spectron test. For example:

```
var electronPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron');
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    electronPath += '.cmd';
}
var appPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", 'app/main/app.js');
appPath = "app/main/app.js";

console.log(appPath);
var app = new Application({
            path: electronPath,
            args: [appPath]
                  });
var app2 = new Application({
            path: electronPath,
            args: [appPath]
                  });

describe('Test Example', function () {

  beforeEach(function () {
      this.timeout(10000);
      return app.start();
  });

  beforeEach(function () {
      this.timeout(10000);
      return app2.start();
  });
```

})

I am a newbie and cannot find an answer. Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Even I am having a similar problem where multiple electron application instances are getting launched.